# Passing HashTable to PowerShell Runbook

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-automation

I think, I read all related posts, still cannot make this work.
I have an Azure Runbook that needs a HashTable parameter passed to a provisioning script. This is used later by the `Apply-PnPTemplate` function.

Parameters declared in the script as

```
[System.Collections.Hashtable] $Parameters = @{}
```

but I also tried

```
[Object] $Parameters = @{}
```

I try to test my script, add `@{"customercode"="TEST"}` as parameter, but I get this error message:

```
Cannot convert the "@{"customercode"="TEST"}" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".
```

What I tried: passing with and without `@`, changing the delimiter to `;;` (I need use this in PowerApps too) and `,`, none of them helped. Please advise, what is the correct way of passing this object to the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced the same issue, seams that it always treats the input as string.

I cannot figure out the reason, but here is a workaround: pass a fake hashtable(string type), then in the runbook, convert the string to hashtable.

Demo code as below, hope it helps.

```
param([string]$mystr)

$mystr = $mystr.replace("=",":")

# pass the string to hashtable

$Parameters = @{}
$jsonobj = $mystr | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach($p in $jsonobj.psobject.properties){$Parameters[$p.name] = $p.value}

#print the keys

write-output "**the keys**"
$Parameters.keys

write-output "**the values**"

#print the values
$Parameters.values
```

The parameters I passed: `{"name"="jack","age"="11","city"="ddd"}`

The test result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
[System.Collections.Hashtable] $Parameters = @{}
$Parameters.add("customercode","TEST")
```